# Behavior of the upload cancel logic

Tags: fine-uploader

Using fine-uploader 4.1.1

Hello, I need some clarification regarding the upload cancel feature.

Is the default behavior to allow a cancelled multi-part upload to S3 to be resumed?

If not resumable, is there a way to allow the upload to be cancelled and still retain the capability to resume?

Also, if not resumable, what happens to the multi-part data after the upload is cancelled?  Is it cleared out of S3 immediately, or does the data linger for the default 7 days?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancelling the upload will remove all traces of it from the handler. So, the default behavior for a cancelled file is for it *not* to be resumed.

Sounds like you'd benefit from the [pause in-progress uploads](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/pause.html) feature. This would allow you to explicitly pause a file and to later resume right where the upload left off. Also, note that the upload will resume if you were to leave the page in the middle of an upload and tried to upload the same file again.

As far as the MPE data:

> After you initiate multipart upload and upload one or more parts, you must either complete or abort multipart upload in order to stop getting charged for storage of the uploaded parts. Only after you either complete or abort multipart upload, Amazon S3 frees up the parts storage and stops charging you for the parts storage.
>   ~ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadInitiate.html

The `abort` MPU request is sent when the upload is cancelled, and the `complete` MPU request is sent when the MPE upload has successfully and completely finished.